# Gradle with a local pom dependency picks up wrong version

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

My build.gradle references a local maven pom. I have enabled the `mavenLocal()` repository and have added the jar as a compile time dependency (eg. my-local-lib, as shown below).

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile (group: 'com.company', name: 'my-local-lib', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT')
}
```

Gradle indeed picks it up and adds it as a dependency. My-local-lib, however, is itself dependent on another library as specified in its pom.xml, but gradle fails to pick up the correct version specified in the pom.xml, and instead chooses a much earlier version. This particular jar dependency is not a dependency on any other library.

Is this a known issue? Could it be due to my-local-lib being a SNAPSHOT version? Is there a way that I can enforce gradle to respect the versions specified in the libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following piece of code:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}
```

to `build.gradle` script.

Comment: Added the code, nothing unfortunately. I really cannot understand where it picks up the specific wrong version... I even tried deleting all local caches of the library both in maven and gradle and rebuilding.

Comment: Maybe you're deleting in the wrong place? Try to remove both maven and gradle cache. Then install the lib. Then run build. Install the lib once again. Run the build again to check the version.

Comment: Tried again but nothing unfortunately. Only thing that works is if I add the dependency explicitly on my build.gradle file.

Comment: Could you please provide an SSCCE?

Comment: I created a maven project with the problematic dependency, deployed it on local. Then I created a gradle project with the maven local dependency, and it all worked fine.. So it must be an issue with my environment. Thing is, I tried the same setup on another machine and had the same issue there too...

Comment: It seems that this is not a problem with gradle but rather with maven. If I understood well, the chain is: gradle -> maven -> maven. You need to configure the first maven to resolve snapshots correctly.

Comment: I just run `gradle dependencies` and get the following: org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:5.5.2 -> 4.10.4. There is no other lib that uses solrj thought, at least not in the rest of the dependencies list. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Oh, there definitely is, because you requested version `5.5.2` and got `4.10.4`. Is there a chance to post the `build.gradle` or at least the whole dependencies?

Comment: OK it turns out it was spring-boot after all. Apparently the spring-boot dependencies parent project provides versions for all libraries, even those not directly used? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-dependency-versions. I added this line: `ext['solr.version'] = '5.5.2'` to build.gradle and it worked